# No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiOptions' in package 'android'

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<manifest android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="3" package="com.tablet3" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <!-- TI_MANIFEST -->
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="actiobar" android:name="actiobarApplication">
        <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->a
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="mob" android:name=".actiobarActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.analytics.TiAnalyticsService"
        />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

I get this error when i add uiOptions to my activity.

```
AndroidManifest.xml:22: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiOptions' in package 'android'
```

I want the ActionBar to come down, so i am actually trying to uiOptions in my Activity.

Comment: This attribute was added in API 14, this is inconsistent with targetSdkVersion 11

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion = "15"/>, i still get the same error. error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiOptions' in package 'android'

Comment: where do you test it? Is the device new enough?

Answer (score 0):

This attribute was added in API 14, but you have specified targetSdkVersion 11

Comment: I changed it to... <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion = "15"/> and should i open in a different emulator altogether.